# using regex to substitute a string expression

Tags: regex

I would like to create a pattern using regex.
here is an example : dark blue red colored.

basically I wanna use regex to create a pattern that would select the expression whatever the color is. something like dark (word) colored

Can anyone help me please.

Comment: "select the expression whatever the color is" - I think I speak for everyone when I say:  what?

Answer (score 0):

The following REGEX allows you to extract the color assuming `dark` and `colored` are static.

Matches in this example:

dark red colored - group(3) = `red`

dark red blue colored - group(6) and group(7) = `red blue`

```
^((dark)\s([a-z]*)\s(colored)|(dark)\s([a-z]*)\s([a-z]*)\s(colored))$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/75OrR6STWtCJ2bmk)